# All twin prime averages in the range $[9, 119]$ are of the form $6(5[3(z-x)]_{\pmod 7} + x)$ for some $x \in \{0,2,3\}, z \in \{0,2,3,4,5\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, twin-primes, derivation-of-formulae

**Question.** Can we come up with a general formula $f(x_5, x_7, x_{11}, \dots, x_{p_n})$ such that each twin prime average $a \in [p_n + 2, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$ is expressible as $f(x_5, \dots, x_{p_n})$ for some $x_5 \in \{0,2,3\}, \ x_7 \in \{0,2,3,4,5\}, \dots, \ x_{p_n} \in \{0,2,3,4,\dots, p_n - 2\}$.  Below I do for the case $n = 4$.

Here is a Desmos graphing calculator link:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c8yjoqcuqb

[image]

**Derivation.**

$$
6(5 y_5 + x_5) \neq \pm 1 \pmod 7 \\ 
5y_5 + x_5  = x_7 \pmod 7 \\
\iff y_5 = [\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 + 7y_7 \\
$$

So
$$
0 \lt 6(5([\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 + 7y_7) + x_5) \lt N \\
\iff 0 \lt (5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 + 35y_7) + x_5 \lt \frac{N}{6} \\
\iff -x_5 - 5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 \lt 35y_7 \lt \frac{N}{6} - x_5 -5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 \\
\frac{-x_5 - 5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7}{35} \lt y_7 \lt \frac{\frac{N}{6} - x_5 - 5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7}{35} \leq \frac{\frac{11^2 -1}{6} - 0 - 0}{35} = \frac{20}{35}
$$
Therefore the only possible solution for $y_7$ is $0$.

This means that all twin prime averages in the range $[9, 119]$ are of the form:

$$
0 \lt f(x_7, x_5) = 6(5[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}]_7 + x_5) \lt N =11^2 -1
$$

---

**Worked Case $n = 5$:**

$$
6(5(7y + [3(x_7 - x_5)]_7)  + x_5) = x_{11} \\
\iff \\
y = \frac{\frac{\frac{x_{11}}{6} - x_5}{5} - [3(x_7 - x_5)]_7}{7} \pmod{11} \\
\iff \\
y = 11z + \left[\frac{\frac{\frac{x_{11}}{6} - x_5}{5} - [3(x_7 - x_5)]_7}{7}\right]_{11} \\
\\ \
\textbf{So:} \\
f(x_{11}, x_7, x_5) = 6\left(5\left(\left[\frac{x_7 - x_5}{5}\right]_7  + 7\left[\frac{\frac{\frac{x_{11}}{6} - x_5}{5} - [3(x_7 - x_5)]_7}{7}\right]_{11}\right) + x_5\right)
$$

---

**Code For Case $n=4$.**

```
def avg_upto_7(x7, x5):
   a = x7 - x5
   a *= 3
   a %= 7
   a *= 5
   a += x5
   a *= 6
   return a

for x7 in range(0, 7):
   if x7 not in {1, 6}:
      for x5 in range(0, 5):
         if x5 not in {1, 4}:
            a = avg_upto_7(x7, x5)
            print(x7, x5, a)
```

**Prints:**

```
0 0 0
0 2 42
0 3 168
2 0 180
2 2 12
2 3 138
3 0 60
3 2 102
3 3 18
4 0 150
4 2 192
4 3 108
5 0 30
5 2 72
5 3 198
```

Comment: It's easy to show such a formula exists (though this approach won't help much in constructing it). First, take an injection $\prod_{k=2}^n\{0,2,\ldots,p_k-2\}\to \mathbb{Z}$, then for $n$ sufficiently large (I suspect $n\ge 4$ suffices), the cardinality of the image is larger than number of twin prime averages in the interval $[p_n+2,p_{n+1}^2-2]$, so we can just use polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @Mastrem Please feel free to explain your approach more in a full answer.  This derivation works for me, and I like its elementary nature.

Comment: 'this approach' refers to the approach in my comment. Of course you can use it to construct a formula for any given $n$, but it requires you compute all the twin primes averages in the interval first. So perhaps it's more accurate to say that a formula constructed using the approach in my comment won't help you in finding twin primes, since you need to find twin primes to construct it in the first place.

Comment: @Mastrem Okay, that's interesting.  The "modular" function formula I'm deriving just requires you to take mult. inverses modulo each prime, so that's why it might not have a nice closed form.  Though, it seems to keep working, so there is indeed _some_ formula such that if it's image value is within the given growing interval bound, that value is a twin prime average (See code output to verify).   Thank you for your interest in this topic!

Comment: @Mastrem I'm wondering now if there is a variable substitution that can be made, because as $x_7,x_5$ range over their valid values $\{0,2,3\}\ni x_5$ etc, I checked that $x_7 - x_5$ covers every residue modulo $7$.  So maybe make the substitution $u = x_7 - x_5$, then recover $x_5, x_7$ from $u$ by adding / subtracting as needed.

The point with this formula is that there might be some intelligent choice of residues $x_q$ so that you can force the function to take on a small enough value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a formula exists, but that isn't very useful, since we need the twin primes to construct it. Consider the domain
$$
S:=\prod_{k=2}^n\{0,2,\ldots,p_k-2\}.
$$
Construct an injection $g:S\to\mathbb{Z}$. There are many options. For example, you could define
$$g(a_2,\ldots,a_n):=\prod_{k=1}^np_k^{a_k}.$$
Now, enumerate $\operatorname{im}(g)\subset \mathbb{Z}$ by $b_1,\ldots,b_{\#S}$. Say there are $m$ twin prime averages in $[p_{n}+2,p_{n+1}^2-1]$ and enumerate them as $c_1,\ldots,c_m$. Assume $m\le\#S$ and define $h:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ by
$$
h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m\left(c_i\cdot\prod_{1\le j\le m,j\neq i}\frac{x-b_j}{b_i-b_j}\right),
$$
then $h(b_i)=c_i$ for all $1\le i\le m$, so $f:=h\circ g$ suffices.

---

Of course, we still need to prove that $m\le \#S$. I leave this to you. Note that $\#S$ grows exponentially in $n$ and $m$ grows about as fast as $n^2\log n$. Now it's just a question of finding some explicit bounds in the literature and messing around with inequalities.

Comment: Mastrem mine doesn't depend upon the twin primes.  It depends upon _all the primes_.  That's different